# Cutting a planar curve through small disks

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $\gamma:I\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ be a $C^2$ curve parameterized by arc length. We suppose that $\gamma$ is a simple closed curve that bounds a bounded domain in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

**Claim.** Given any $\delta>0$, but sufficiently small, there exists $\varepsilon>0$ such that
\begin{equation}
|\gamma(I)\cap B_\varepsilon|<\delta
\end{equation}
for any ball of radius $\varepsilon$. Here, $|\cdot|$ denotes the length of the set.

**Question.** How to prove the claim?

**PS.** I can prove this statement using Lebesgue's number lemma, but in this way, I cannot see how the curvature comes into play. Instead, I need an estimate of $\varepsilon$ in terms of $\delta$ and the maximum curvature of $\gamma$. Any suggestion?

Comment: This may sound naive but I can't pin down what prevents the curve from being a fractal given the stated predicates.

Comment: I don't get your doubt. When $\varepsilon \to 0$ the length goes to zero. And the trace of the curve is a compact set.

Comment: I just tried to reverse thinking the problem: one way for this claim not being true is to deal with some kind of fractal. But I'm thinking now probably a curve parameterized by arc length can't be a fractal as it doesn't really make sense to talk about the length of a fractal curve, there must be a more rigorous explanation though.